# Webscraping sneaker's size

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to create a script to run against the Nike website at this url:

```
https://www.nike.com/it/t/scarpa-air-force-1-07-lKPQ6q/CW2288-111
```

I eventually want to get the availability (stock level) of the item on the page but my first problem is understanding why the script below gives me an empty output. I'd like to understand if it's possible?

**Code:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://www.nike.com/it/t/scarpa-air-force-1-07-lKPQ6q/CW2288-111'
api_url = 'https://api.nike.com'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

input_tag = soup.find(attrs={"value": "25634224:11"})
output = input_tag['input']
str (output)
```

Comment: The problem you're facing is that the web site is dynamic.  Go do a "view source" to look at it in your browser: there are no HTML elements with shoes in them.  The data is sent as a JSON object, and the HTML is created by Javascript on the page.  You're not executing the Javascript.  You can either pull the data from the JSON in the `<script>` tags, or use Selenium to run the Chrome browser to execute the Javascript.

Comment: outshined: I've edited the question as it was getting downvoted.  Just include the problem and where you are stuck when posting again :o)

Answer (score 1):

Some pages cannot be "just scraped" as the page content (text and images etc.) only gets generated if/when a browser loads the page.  You can use [`Selenium`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/index.html) ([pip install](https://pypi.org/project/selenium/)).

**Example code of opening the page with Selenium:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.3"
}

# set the url
url = 'https://www.nike.com/it/t/scarpa-air-force-1-07-lKPQ6q/CW2288-111'

# keeping it simple: download from https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads (match version of Chrome installed)
# put the extracted file in same folder as the script.  Firefox driver is available if you search for it
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# open Chrome and go to the url
driver.get(url)

# wait for the page to load
sleep(3)

# get the program to clear the cookies pop-ups etc.  These may or may not work for you but as an example at least...
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='gen-nav-commerce-header-v2']/aside/div/button/i").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='gen-nav-commerce-header-v2']/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/button").click()

# get the page
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

# close the browser as you have the source of the page in the soup object
driver.close()

# below add code to search and filter the soup object.
# ......
# ........
# ..........
```

If you get stuck with how to click things or enter text via the script first comment out the `driver.close()` line so it stays open.  Then read the docs for Selenium (linked above).  You can [fill in forms](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/navigating.html#filling-in-forms) etc. and do quite a lot.